Room data isn't being collected by kotlin flow in test
Here's my dao:
@Dao
interface CoverLettersDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM CoverLetter ORDER BY timestamp DESC")
fun collectLetters(): Flow<List<CoverLetter>>
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertOne(coverLetter: CoverLetter)
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertAll(coverLetters: List<CoverLetter>)

view model code related to the problem:
init {
    collectCoverLetters()
}
private fun collectCoverLetters() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        coverLettersDao.collectLetters().collectLatest { lettersList ->
            println("Collected letters: $lettersList")
            _uiState.update { it.copy(letters = lettersList) }
        }
    }
}

fun getCoverLetters(startAt: Int) {
    updateFetchResult(CustomResult.InProgress)
    viewModelScope.launch {
            val letters = homeRepository.getCoverLetters(batchSize, lastLetter = _uiState.value.letters.getOrNull(startAt))
             coverLettersDao.insertAll(letters)
             _uiState.update { it.copy(letters = it.letters + letters) }
             ...
}

test dispatcher rule:
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class DispatcherRule(
val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
): TestWatcher() {
override fun starting(description: Description?) {
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
}
override fun finished(description: Description?) {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
}
}

the test:
@get: Rule
val dispatcherRule = DispatcherRule()

@Test
fun getCoverLetters_success() = runTest {
    viewModel.getCoverLetters(0)
    advanceUntilIdle()
    println(viewModel.uiState.value.letters)
 }

the list gets displayed as empty, and the println("Collected letters: $lettersList") doesn't execute. but everything works correctly when i call advanceUntilIdle lots of times.
